# Homepage Magento White Screen

Tags: magento

I need your assistants. I have been working on my magento store and have run into a problem. I created an account a member account to test if everything is ok, since doing that i now notice on my homepage there is a blank white screen, it will not show me anything, here is a link to the blank homepage

http://www.weldersdirect.com.au/

For all the toher pages i can get access just fine, it seems to be only the homepage that is blank. Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks Everyone

Ali

Comment: what error are you getting in error log file?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have invalid php in either the index.php itself, unlikely though.
Or the error lies somewhere within the /app/design/frontend/(yourtheme)/default/template/page/1column.php

Something unique to the homepage is causing it to crash. Most likely you only use one-column for the homepage. Looks like the other pages all are using two-columns

Comment: Just noticed as well, Privacy Policy, About Us, Customer service are also all broken in the same manor for you. Again the uniqueness is that they are all using 1column.php template